# Does a complete field have only finitely many extensions of bounded degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $R$ be a complete DVR with fraction field $K$. Let $d\geq 1$ be an integer.
>   Does $K$ have only finitely many extensions of degree $d$?

If $K=\mathbb Q_p$ the answer is yes. Is this a general fact about complete DVRs?

Comment: If you take a field $k$ which has infinitely many extensions of degree $d$ and take $K$ to be the field of Laurent series with coefficients in $k$, what happens?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ow right, I see. Then there must be some condition on the residue field. What if we assume the residue field (of the valuation ring) to have only finitely many extensions of bounded degree?

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/353928/11619) for some discussion that is AFAICT relevant to your topic. Note that $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\Bbb{F}_p((X))$ behave differently in this respect.