# Algebraic closure of $Q_p$ is composite of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm wondering about the following:
Let $K$ be a numberfield and $v$ a place of $K$. Is it true that the algebraic closure $\bar{K_v}$ of $K_v$ is the composite of the fields $K_v$ and $\bar{K}$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Let $K=\Bbb Q_p(\alpha)$ be a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$.
Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q_p$.

If the coefficients of $g$ are sufficiently close to those of $\alpha$,
then $K=\Bbb Q_p(\beta)$ where $\beta$ is a zero of $g$ (this is essentially a Hensel's lemma argument). We can choose $g$ to have
rational coefficients, so that $\beta$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I need more details on the proof. For example, is it possible to enumerate all the extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $\le n$ ?

Comment: @reuns Look up [Krasner's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasner%27s_lemma). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/353964/11619) for a link as well as a discussion why that fails for char $p$ local fields.

Comment: I don't see how it is deduced by hensel's lemma. But using krasner's lemma its clear to me.

Comment: @NeukirchLover You use Hensel's Lemma to prove Krasner's Lemma

Comment: Ok I see, thanks! Just for a reference: the proof I have in mind is in cohomology of number fields, Lemma 8.1.6.